# Is this the idiomatic way to draw/redraw widget components?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

new to Svelte and unsure if this is the proper way to make material widgets appear/hide/redraw (in this case I'm using Carbon by IBM). Essentially I use a boolean variable for every widget that I want to control and use it to dictate what should render.  Is there a better way?

```
<script>
    import { Button } from 'carbon-components-svelte';
    let loading_finished: boolean;
    async function initAnalysis() {
         // Do stuff for a while..
        loading_finished = true;
    }

   let analysis_finished: boolean;
   async function runAnalysis() {
         // Do stuff for a while..
        analysis_finished = true;
    }
</script>

<Button on:click={initAnalysis}>Load Inputs</Button>

{#if loading_finished}
   <Button on:click={runAnalysis}>Run Analysis</Button>
{/if}

{#if analysis_finished}
   Analysis is finished
{/if}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the logic.

If all the flags are exclusive, you can use a state variable to replace multiple booleans instead. So something like:

```html
{#if state == 'init'}
  ...
{:else if state == 'processing'}
  ...
{:else if state == 'finished'}
  ...
{/if}
```

Or instead of using `{#if}` you could toggle visibility using a class (which means the element always exists but is hidden), though in this case you would have to deactivate the default scoping because the buttons are components rather than regular DOM elements.